jq doesn't return non-zero for empty input
I have this line of code that works as expected:
echo '{"slot":"we"}' | jq -re '.slot' || exit 1

however this code doesn't raise an error even though I would expect so:
echo ' ' | jq -re '.slot' || exit 1

and neither does this:
echo '' | jq -re '.slot' || exit 1

how can I make sure that it raises an error if slot key is not found? What I mean is that in both last two examples the exit code is 0


This might be your issue: echo '' | jq -e '.slot' exited with code 0 for older versions of jq (until and including jq 1.6). Since jq 1.7 it exits with code 4. (See #1697)

Re "how can I make sure that it raises an error if "slot" key is not found?": Test it using has/1, and call one of error/0, error/1, halt_error/0, or halt_error/1, according to your surrounding logic.

Your code works fine with jq 1.7. If you're using jq 1.6 you need this:
jq -nre 'inputs.slot'

